# How save an image from gallery to internal memory using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create an app that will enable a user to select an image from the gallery and then save it into the apps internal memory. I am able to successfully retrieve the Uri of the image using rememberLauncherForActivityResult. However, after that I am stuck on how to save it to my internal memory and then be able to retrieve the images when required. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You just copy the file to the new location. Why is that a problem? Can you copy a file that is already somewhere in private storage of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Composable function to handle the image selection and saving

```
@Composable
fun ImageSelectionScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        onResult = { uri: Uri? ->
            uri?.let { saveImageToInternalStorage(context, it) }
        }
    )

    Button(onClick = { launcher.launch("image/*") }) {
        Text(text = "Select Image")
    }
}

fun saveImageToInternalStorage(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
    val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
    val outputStream = context.openFileOutput("image.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    inputStream?.use { input ->
        outputStream.use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

Use the ImageSelectionScreen Composable in your app's UI

```
setContent {
    ImageSelectionScreen()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you also help me with then retrieving the images from the internal storage so that I can display it in my app.